# how to traverse a Boolean recursion array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, boolean

**The exercise:**
Build a recursion(with no loops) that every cell that you go inside is the number of steps that you can go, it could be right/left until you get to the last cell. if you can't get to the last cell return false, else return true.
you must start from index 0.

***My problem***: I build the program, it's not working, ,i am able to get to last cell but in the output i get false, i understand why i get false but i don't know how to fix it.

**Test:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
// Q - isWay
        System.out.println("\nTesting Question 3\n==================");
        int[] a1 = {2,4,1,6,4,2,4,3,5};
        System.out.println("a = {2,4,1,6,4,2,4,3,5}");
        System.out.println("Ex14.isWay(a) is: " + Ex14.isWay(a1)); //need to return true
        int[] a2 = {1,4,3,1,2,4,3};
        System.out.println("a2 = {1,4,3,1,2,4,3}");
        System.out.println("Ex14.isWay(a2) is: " + Ex14.isWay(a2));//need to return false
}


public class Ex14
{
    public static boolean isWay(int[] a)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if(a.length <= 1)
                return false;
            return isWay(a , 0);
        }

        public static boolean isWay(int[] a,int i)
        {     
            int temp1 , temp2;
            if(i == a.length-1)
                return true;
            if(!((a[i]+i < a.length) && (i-a[i] >= 0))) // can't go right and left
                return false;
            else if(a[i] > 0)
            {
                if(a[i]+i < a.length) // go right
                {
                    temp1 = a[i] + i;
                    a[i] = -1;
                    return isWay(a, temp1);
                }
                else if (i-a[i] >= 0) // go left
                {
                    temp2 = i - a[i];
                    a[i] = -1;
                    return isWay(a, temp2);   
                }    
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: ok ... I'm not exactly sure what it is you're asking. could you please be more clear?

Comment: sure, i am new in recursion, now i don't understand what i am not doing good in the recursion that i get always false, i hope that you can show me the mistake and explain what i am doing wrong.

Comment: it seems to me your recursion works, it 's just the logic you implemented that is flawed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition for returning `false` is wrong.

```
if(!((a[i]+i < a.length) && (i-a[i] >= 0)))
```

should be

```
if(!((a[i]+i < a.length) || (i-a[i] >= 0)))
```

You want to return `false` if you can't proceed either left **or** right. Your condition tests whether you can't proceed both left **and** right.

EDIT:

My original suggested fix wasn't enough, since your method must be able to back-track if you reach a dead end.

Here's an alternative approach:

```
public static boolean isWay(int[] a,int i) {
    int temp1 , temp2;
    if(i == a.length-1) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean found = false;
    if(a[i]+i < a.length && a[a[i]+i] > 0) { // go right
        temp1 = a[i] + i;
        a[i] = -1;
        found = isWay(a, temp1);
        if (!found) {
            a[i] = temp1 - i; // must restore a[i] to its original value, in order 
                              // to be able to go left
        }
    }
    if (!found && i-a[i] >= 0 && a[i - a[i]] > 0) { // go left
        temp2 = i - a[i];
        a[i] = -1;
        found = isWay(a, temp2);   
    }
    return found;
}
```

The idea is that if you can go both left and right, and going right leads to a dead end, you must try to go left when the recursive call for going right returns.

This returns true for both `{1,4,3,6,1,2,4,3}` and `{2,4,1,6,4,2,4,3,5}`.

Comment: thank you for responding.this is not the problem if i can't go left and right so i am stuck and i need to return false else i keep going with the problem

Comment: @asaf Yes, but if you **can** go right but **can't** go left, you should go right instead of returning false.

Comment: 1. i tried what you said, it still now workking                                                      2.this condition is only if i am stuck so i need return false else i keep going

Comment: @asaf I tried the fixed code with the `{1,4,3,6,1,2,4,3}` array. It returns true, as it should (0->1->5->7).

Comment: now try this one, it also need to return true **{2,4,1,6,4,2,4,3,5}**

Comment: @asaf I see. Your recursive method must be able to backtrack when you reach a dead end.

Comment: see this '{1,4,3,1,2,4,3}' it get to endless loop so it need to return false but return also true

Comment: @asaf I had a small bug. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you want to do but here is an example of a recursive function that effective && all booleans in an array

```
public static boolean recurse(boolean[] ary)
{
    if (ary.length == 1) {
        return ary[0];
    }

    return ary[0] && recurse(Arrays.copyOfRange(ary, 1, ary.length));
}
```

Test :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean[] ary = { true, true, true, true, true};

    System.out.println(recurse(ary));

    boolean[] ary2 = { true, true, false, true, true};

    System.out.println(recurse(ary2)); 
}
```

- True
- False

I hope that help you to resolve your problem else you can explain more what you want to do with this function

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 2, 4, 1, 6, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5 };
    System.out.println(isWay(a)); // true

    int[] a1 = { 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3 };
    System.out.println(isWay(a1)); // false
}

public static boolean isWay(int[] a)
{
    return isWay(a, 0);
}

private static boolean isWay(int[] a, int i)
{
    if (i == a.length - 1) // if we are in the last index
        return true;

    if (i >= a.length || i < 0) // boundaries
        return false;
    
    if (a[i] == -1) // if marked return false to prevent infinite recursion..
        return false;

    int temp = a[i]; // mark where we already have been...
    a[i] = -1;

    boolean r1 = isWay(a, i + temp); // we are trying to move right
    boolean r2 = isWay(a, i - temp); // we are trying to move left

    a[i] = temp; // revert changes

    return r1 || r2;
}
```